# Sitecore Field Validator Change to Custom Message

Tags: validation

I have a field that is a required field validator in Sitecore. 
I marked that field as required and Set the `parameter=FatalError` so that users cannot save the item without entering data in that field.

The issue though is, I am not able to change the custom message when the user saves it. I get the standard message that says

```
"Some of the fields in this item contain fatal errors. You must resolve these errors before you can save this item".
```

I changed the title, description and text field but looks like it is not picking up from there. Any idea where should I change that message?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OOTB, you cannot change this message because this is present in the Sitecore Kernel dll. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

In order to change this message, you will need to override the validators pipeline

```
<processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Validators, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

So, it will be something as below:

```
public class CustomValidators
{
    public void Process(SaveArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        this.ProcessInternal((ClientPipelineArgs)args);
    }

    protected void ProcessInternal(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        if (args.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (args.Result == "no")
            {
                args.AbortPipeline();
            }
            args.IsPostBack = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string formValue = WebUtil.GetFormValue("scValidatorsKey");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formValue))
                return;
            ValidatorCollection validators = ValidatorManager.GetValidators(ValidatorsMode.ValidatorBar, formValue);
            ValidatorOptions options = new ValidatorOptions(true);
            ValidatorManager.Validate(validators, options);
            Pair<ValidatorResult, BaseValidator> strongestResult = ValidatorManager.GetStrongestResult(validators, true, true);
            ValidatorResult part1 = strongestResult.Part1;
            BaseValidator part2 = strongestResult.Part2;
            if (part2 != null && part2.IsEvaluating)
            {
                SheerResponse.Alert("The fields in this item have not been validated.\n\nWait until validation has been completed and then save your changes.");
                args.AbortPipeline();
            }
            else if (part1 == ValidatorResult.CriticalError)
            {
                string text = Translate.Text("Some of the fields in this item contain critical errors.\n\nAre you sure you want to save this item?");
                if (MainUtil.GetBool(args.CustomData["showvalidationdetails"], false) && part2 != null)
                    text += ValidatorManager.GetValidationErrorDetails(part2);
                SheerResponse.Confirm(text);
                args.WaitForPostBack();
            }
            else
            {
                if (part1 != ValidatorResult.FatalError)
                    return;

                // Changes to validation message goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have copied the code from the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` at the namespace `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Validators`. You can dotpeek that dll and see how sitecore implemented the fatal error message.

Finally, you need to patch the config file to add yours:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <saveUI>
        <processor patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Validators, Sitecore.Kernel']"
            type="YourNamespace, YourAssemblyName" />
      </saveUI>      
    </processors>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you .  While this makes no sense from sitecore perspective that we cant override the message, atleast it helps me what i need to do now..