# Popup dialog when saving an item to alert user to a required field

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to implement a popup when trying to implement a popup to alert users to a required field, but running into an error with even loading the CMS after trying to create the code:

```
Could not instantiate event handler. Type: DVD.Utility.DVDItemSavingProcessor. Method: DialogProcessor (method: Sitecore.Events.Event.GetConfigSubscribers()).
```

Here are my pieces of code:

Config:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saving">
        <handler type="DVD.Utility.DVDItemSavingProcessor, DVD" method="DialogProcessor"/>
     </event>
   </events>
  </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

Processor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;

namespace DVD.Utility
{
    public class DVDItemSavingProcessor 
    {
        
        private void StartDialog()
        {
            // Start the dialog and pass in an item ID as an argument
            ClientPipelineArgs cpa = new ClientPipelineArgs();
            cpa.Parameters.Add("id", Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString());

            // Kick off the processor in the client pipeline
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", cpa);
        }
        protected void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            var id = args.Parameters["id"];

            if (!args.IsPostBack)
            {
                Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
                if (item.TemplateName == "Image" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Fields["Alt"].ToString()))
                {
                    SheerResponse.Alert("Please fill in the Alt Tag field");
                }
                
                // Suspend the pipeline to wait for a postback and resume from another processor
                args.WaitForPostBack(true);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to implement the event handler for the `item:saving` is to add the parameters sender and arguments. I've updated the `StartDialog` method as shown below.

```
public void StartDialog(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var savedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

    if (savedItem == null || savedItem.Database.Name.ToLower() != "master")
    {
        return;
    }

    // Start the dialog and pass in an item ID as an argument
    ClientPipelineArgs cpa = new ClientPipelineArgs();
    cpa.Parameters.Add("id", savedItem.ID.ToString());

    // Kick off the processor in the client pipeline
    Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", cpa);
}
```

And your config will look like this

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saving">
        <handler type="DVD.Utility.DVDItemSavingProcessor, DVD" method="StartDialog"/>
     </event>
   </events>
  </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

**Best Approach - Using OOTB Sitecore**

Instead of creating a custom dialog, you can make use of the Sitecore Validators. Based on the code you've provided, it shows that you want to show a popup if the `alt` field is blank.

You can actually do this without any code change using OOTB Sitecore feature. However, Alt Text validation is set to Error and this will still allow the media item to be saved. You'll need to update the `Alt Required` validator item by adding`Result=FatalError`. See screenshot below:

[image]

Item path: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/System/Alt Required`.

**Create Your Own Validator**

You can also create your own validator. Below is a snippet of a custom validator

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Validators;

namespace Sitecore.Experimental
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AltValidator : StandardValidator
    {
        // Constructors required, else error is thrown when clicking the Validation button in the Content Editor
        public ItemUrlConflictValidation(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

        public ItemUrlConflictValidation() { }

        protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
        {
            var database = Database.GetDatabase("master");
            
            if (this.ItemUri != null)
            {
                var currentItem = database.GetItem(this.ItemUri.ItemID, this.ItemUri.Language);

                if (currentItem.TemplateName == "Image" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItem.Fields["Alt"].ToString()))
                {
                    this.Text = this.GetText("Alternate text is missing in the Image field.", this.GetFieldDisplayName());
                    return this.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.FatalError);
                }
            }

            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }

        protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
        {
            return this.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.FatalError);
        }

        public override string Name => "AltFieldValidator";
    }
}
```

Once you have the code in place, you just need to create a validation rule at the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules`. You can create your own direction if needed.

Then you'll need to populate the different fields. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Then you can assign the new validation item to the fields from the template.

**Point to note**

The error message that will be displayed is a default Sitecore one. If you want to override the default message to a custom one, you can check the answer for question [Sitecore Field Validator Change to Custom Message](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8900/605)

Comment: +1 for OOTB Sitecore

Comment: I tried the OOTB option, but it seems like the Text=Parameter doesn't change the message?  Neither does the Text field in the Text section.  I'm wondering if these fields items do anything.  Am I clear that if I want to customize the popup text I will need to override the save validator as in the linked post?  Or would the initial item:saving processor do the trick?

Comment: Those are used in the right side bar and also near the fields. You’ll see a red highlight near the fields and when hovering on it, it shows the message. In the answer, at the Point to note, I’ve pasted a link on where to change the default message

Comment: The Point to note option you linked to I've been trying to get to work but running into an error, so will post about that separately, thanks.